# Image upload for multiple fields Angular 5

Tags: angular5, angular-material2, image-upload

I have a scenario where i have to create multiple file upload fields dynamically using reactive forms with form array  and upload multiple image for that particular field in angular 5 or angular reactive forms and the image needs to be displayed parallel to that form field name .
Please help with me with any sample code in stack blitz or from any links. Also

thanks.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have created a form Array with file upload and on select i am able to get the index of the file upload button. Now i need to know how i can upload the multiple image and display only to that form control of file upoad

Answer (score 1):

You can do the file upload part using `formData`.

```
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file1', file1, file1.name);
    formData.append('file2', file2, file2);
    this.http.post(url, formData);
```

And using the change event in the

`<input type="file" (chnage)="onChange($event)">` you can get the image source of the file you select.

Here

```
public fileList: FileList;
public imageUrls: any[];
public files: any[];

 public onChange(event) {
    if (event.target.files.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    this.fileList = event.target.files;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.fileList.length; i++) {
      const file = this.fileList[i];
      if (!file.type.match('image')) {
        continue;
      }
      this.files.push(file);
      const picReader = new FileReader();
      picReader.onload = (e: any) => {
        const picFile = e.target;
        this.imageUrls.push(picFile.result);
      };
      picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
```

And in the template

```
  <input type="file"
           (change)="onChange($event)"
           placeholder="Upload file"
           accept="image/*" multiple>
    <p>(You may choose more than one file to upload.)</p>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of imageUrls; let i = index">

      <img [src]="item" height="100" class="img-thumbnail">
    </ng-container>
```

This is just a idea. Just give it a try.

Comment: The code has an issue with  this.files.push(file); which is not recognising the tag , having said that i have a formArray this.documentSubmission this.formBuilder.group({ 'invoiceparticulars': this.formBuilder.array([]), }); and from that there are 2 formcontrols created one for file and other for name and the fields will be dynamically created based on the length the services provide. I need to know how can i bind one image to one field and second image to another field

Comment: I've update the answer. Best is to create a stackblitz with what you have tried so far.

Comment: I will try to create one and try to send it

Comment: I have created the dynamic form and when changed the number from 2 to any , the file would be created n number of times.

Comment: I have fixed this issue with ng-compress, works fine